# How do I make an array of specific files in a directory using the command shell in linux?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I have been trying to add files smaller than 2 Megabytes in a directory to an array and then add those files to git and then commit.

```
  find . -type f -size -2M
  i=0
  while read line
  do
    array[ $i ]="$line"
    (( i++ ))
  done
  for item in "${array[@]}"
  do
    git add "$item"
  done
  git commit -am "${COMMIT_MESSAGE}"
```

The script is supposed to add and commit files below 2M. But my script is adding and committing all the files (including the ones larger than 2M).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste your code in your question, not as an image. It's much more likely to get you an answer that way.

Comment: Try `git add $(find . -type f -size -2M); git commit -m "Commit message"`

Comment: what is connecting your `find` to the `while read line` loop? Surely you want `find .... | while read line ...` But above comment looks very usable. Good luck.

Comment: @bobsterman That helped. thanks a lot.

Comment: the largest questions is "*which shell*"? not all support arrays (POSIX, Bourne, etc..)

Comment: @bobsterman, bad, bad things happen there if you have filenames with spaces. See entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The question has been tagged `bash` from the beginning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, just read below that its a common antipattern. it makes sense why it fails, but a bit sad as my command reads nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short form: Resolving the immediate problem

First, with respect to correctly reading files from `find`, follow the advice in [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436429/14122).

Second, as to why your existing code includes all files already added to git in some past revision, as opposed to only those under 2MB, despite not running `git add` *at all*: That's because you're passing the `-a` argument to `git commit`.

```
find . -type f -size -2M -exec git add -- {} +
git commit -m "Commit message" # no -a here!
```

---

#### Long form: Explaining the problem

To be clear as to what I mean by "despite not running `git add` *at all*" above -- as currently written, the output of `find` isn't actually passed into the `while read` loop.

```
find .
while read ...
```

doesn't redirect the output of `find` into the `while read` loop. Thus, your `while read line` loop iterates only on input given to your script on stdin, if any (and the output of `find` is written to stdout).

For other issues, see notes below.

---

#### Long form: Answering the question as-asked

Now, to answer your *literal* question, about how to build a shell array, doing it right looks like the following:

```
# correctly building a shell array
files=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  files+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type f -size -2M -print0)

## using that array efficiently (if not huge)
#git add -- "${files[@]}"

# using that array efficiently (if potentially huge)
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 git add --
```

Implementation notes:

- Putting the `while` loop in the outer shell ensures that changes to variable state that it makes are accessible after it finishes running. Using the `< <(...)` idiom is necessary to do so, as given in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- Passing multiple files to a single `git add` instance is much more efficient than calling `git add` once per file.
- Using the `-print0` argument to `find` causes filenames to be separated by NULs (which, unlike newline literals, cannot possibly exist in filenames) in `find`'s output.
- Using the `IFS= read -r -d '' file` idiom (as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)) reads names from `find` in byte-for-byte literal form.
- Using `array+=( "$value" )` is much, much easier than keeping an integer index counter and incrementing it between each append.

Comment: And for those who live in the future (Bash 4.4 to be released very soon): `mapfile -t -d '' files < <(find . -type f -size -2M -print0)`. With the usual caveat that `-print0` is not standard…

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` to run `git add`.

```
find . -type f -size -2M -exec git add {} +
```

This will work for *all* valid file names.

The `-a` option to `commit` is probably not necessary. If you only have untracked large files, they won't be added by `commit -a` anyway, and you've already added all the modified small files. However, you do need to drop it if you have large tracked files with modifications that you don't want to include in the pending commit.

Comment: Let's say I "implied" it; makes me sound slightly less careless :)

Comment: (But initially adding the `-exec` in the wrong position does make me careless, alas.)

Comment: `-a` is only a problem if you don't want to commit modified, but already tracked, large files. The assumption here seems to be that `find` is being used in place of `git add *` to avoid adding large untracked files to the repo.

Comment: The OP is very explicit that their immediate problem spawning the question is that all files are being committed. Can you see how their prior code would have done that without the `-a` being a problem?

Comment: "add and commit" implies they aren't already in the repository, which means `commit -a` would ignore them.

Comment: I agree with you about git's behavior, but I don't see how one can get the symptom the OP described from the code they provided unless they genuinely don't want previously-added-and-modified files to be committed if over 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
find . -type f -size -2M -print0 | xargs -0 git add
git commit -m 'Message here'
```

Comment: `xargs` should not be used with `find`, unless you use `find`'s `-print0` and `xargs`'s `-0` switches (which are not standard anyway). With `find`, use `-exec`, as in chepner's answer.

Comment: Missed that this was edited until today. Much better now.

Answer (score -2):

the one-line command from the first comment is good
but if you still need a script in order to add some extra logic try to use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

root_dir="/home/myuser/myproject"
exclude_path="dirname_to_exclude"
max_size="-2048k"

for file in $(find $root_dir -type f -size $max_size | grep -v $exclude_path)
do
    git add $file
done

git commit -m "blablabla..."
```

Comment: `for file in $(find ...)` is (sadly!) a very common antipattern: it's broken with filenames containing spaces or glob characters (and it spawns a useless subshell). See chepner's answer for the proper way to use `find`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls entry #1, or (for the Right Way to do it) http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: Also, `git add $file` is broken itself -- look at what it does with a file with either spaces or globs in its name (for instance, if `file='*** READ ME FIRST ***.txt'`). Needs to be `git add "$file"` to prevent string-splitting or glob expansion, and likewise for all your other unquoted globs. (Unquoted expansions can break on more than whitespace -- if other code in your script set `IFS=/`, for instance, an unquoted expansion will make every directory element its own word)..